# How to get the {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails} in apex code?

Tags: experience-cloud, merge-field

I want to send the experience community welcome email invitation link via Phone SMS. For that reason, I need the value of {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails} in runtime in apex code.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Two *untested* ideas:

1. You can render an email template to a string using renderEmailTemplate() - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_renderemailtemplate.htm so in theory, you could render that email template to a string, and pull the URL out of that using a regex.
2. You could, I think, generate a VF Page to pull that out, and use PageReference.getContents() to pull out the URL. getContents() does count as a callout.